# синхронизация изменений удаленного репозитория и локального

Tags: git, git-pull

Как можно с помощью команды `git pull` тащить себе в локальный репозиторий все изменения?

Сейчас пишет:

> There is no tracking information for the current branch.
>   Please specify which branch you want to merge with.

До этого получалось через:

```
git fetch 
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: git pull origin master:master?

Answer (score 5):

вероятно, вы создали новую ветку (`ваша-новая-ветка`) и при выполнении `git pull` получаете такое сообщение:

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> новая-ветка
```

прямо в сообщении присутствует подсказка. краткий пересказ:

1. для одноразового «вливания» из (например) ветки `master` из репозитория `origin` выполните:

   ```
   $ git pull origin master
   ```
2. для того, чтобы в этой ветке можно было выполнять `git pull` без аргументов, и при этом происходило «вливание» из ветки `master` репозитория `origin`, выполните:

   ```
   $ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master ваша-новая-ветка
   ```